# How to properly deal with "zombie" Kafka Consumers in Reactive Spring Boot applications

Tags: project-reactor

We have a Reactive Spring Boot application that employs "reactor-kafka" for Kafka consumers and producers.

we use 1 `KafkaReceiver` per topic, that is subscribed to and kept in a Spring bean field.

I observe that sometimes, some or all of the underlying `Consumer`-s just stop with an error message as follows:

> "[Consumer clientId=consumer-my-service-2-11, groupId=my-service-2] Member consumer-my-service-2-11-2ebeee54-566c-4ae8-ac43-1d5710fee1fa sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 192.168.0.224:14493 (id: 2147483619 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records."

(this is the last message in the log thus far; the application lives happily for a day already, after all 11 of consumers have stuck in this limbo; topic is consumed by other pods)

Regardless of what the error says, should not consumer still be restarted by the library/Kafka internals? Or should it be application author's responsibility to somehow track this state and react accordingly (for example, by implementing liveness health check around this somehow)?

Java: 11

kafka-clients: 2.8.1

reactor-kafka: 1.3.17